# Node int overflowing?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone explain this:

```
$node -v
v0.10.10

$ node
> (10000000)>>1
5000000
> (100000000)>>1
50000000
> (1000000000)>>1
500000000
> (10000000000)>>1
705032704
```

Shouldn't be 2^53 the max int representation according to ECMA Section 8.5 - Numbers?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [ECMAScript specification on `>>`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.2), the left operand is passed into the abstract operation [`ToInt32`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.6) whose description reads:

> The abstract operation ToUint32 converts its argument to one of 2<sup>32</sup> integer values in the range -2<sup>31</sup> through 2<sup>31</sup>−1, inclusive.

And whose behavior is specified as:

> - Let *posInt* be sign(*number*) × floor(abs(*number*)).
> - Let *int32bit* be *posInt* modulo 2<sup>32</sup>; that is, a finite integer value k of Number type with positive sign and less than 2<sup>32</sup> in magnitude
> - If *int32bit* is greater than or equal to 2<sup>31</sup>, return *int32bit* − 2<sup>32</sup>, otherwise return *int32bit*.

Thus, no result from `>>` can be greater than 2<sup>31</sup>, and any value that would be greater is transformed by modulo 3<sup>32</sup> (with negative overflow for values greater than 2<sup>31</sup>).

Answer (score -1):

It seems that bitwise operators only work in 32bits.

Comment: Do you guess or do you know? ;)